# Firebase and Socket.io compatibility issue crash my app

Tags: android, firebase, sockets

Every time add firebase dependencies, run my app and socket connect to endpoint, my app crashes immediately.

I'm using firebase and socket.io together and is causing the crash due to compatibility issues. Can firebase and socket.io be used together?

I get the following error when i added firebase and try to connect to socket.io in my project

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.project.hubrydemanagerapp, PID: 30101
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callEngineGetConnection(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Call;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection; in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.project.hubrydemanagerapp-t3ZbPD-QZAE9y2BMT64Cdg==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(WebSocketCall.java:154)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(WebSocketCall.java:42)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(WebSocketCall.java:102)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

Endpoint

```
    "https://hubryde-trip-service.herokuapp.com/";
    "https://hubryde-request-service.herokuapp.com/";
```

Connection. I'm using Application class to create socket model.

```
        tripSocket = IO.socket(TRIP_URL);
        socket2 = IO.socket(BUS_URL);

        SocketEndpoint app = (SocketEndpoint) getApplication();
        tripSocket = app.getmTripSocket();
        if(!tripSocket.connected()) {
            tripSocket.connect();
        }
        socket2 = app.getmBusLocationSocket();
        if(!socket2.connected()) {
            socket2.connect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your dependencies and i realized firestore dependency is the reason for the crash not the entire firebase dependencies. It seems not to support The type of socket.io you are using OR not even support socket.io at all.

I even went further to test older version of cloud firestore, but no luck - The app keeps crashing with the same error.

So remove firestore and sync your project if you will see the error.

Answer (score 7):

Im also Using com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0.
That crash also happened to me after adding firebase in app messaging module,
for me the quick fix (until this will be fixed, hopefully soon..)
was to add exclude.. 
hope it helps..

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
}
```

my full gradle file: (Using AndroidX)

```
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
implementation 'tech.gusavila92:java-android-websocket-client:1.2.2'
implementation  "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
}
```

Comment: This can happen for `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore` too. Add the same exclude command.